# появилось значение с пустого места

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const TelegramApi = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const bot = new TelegramApi(token, {polling:true})

const start =  () => {

    bot.setMyCommands([
        {command: '/start', description: 'Начальное приветствие'},
        {command: '/pay', description: 'Купить ключ'},
        {command: '/about', description: 'О боте'}
    ])
}

bot.on('message', msg => {
    const text = msg.text
    const chatId = msg.from.id;

    if(text === "/start") {
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Ку бро, чтобы купить ключ нажми на / и выбери /pay')
    }

    if (text === "/pay") {
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Чтобы купить ключ перейди на ссылку qiwi.com/n/FUNTIC и переведи' +
            ' сумму равную 350 рублей с комментарием "#1"')
    }
})
```

/game с пустого места появилось

Comment: Вот здесь почитай [TGapi](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmycommands)

Comment: @Rudi мне надо прописать так ? bot.deleteMyCommands(language_code = "/game") ?

Comment: Возможно Ваш токен бота используется где-то ещё, смените его, на всякий случай